# Tratar Json Array em PHP

Tags: php, json

Como faço para pegar determinado item de uma array em PHP.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['newUsers'])) {
    $newUsers = $_POST['newUsers'];
    foreach ($newUsers as $user) {
        $usr = json_decode($user);
        var_dump($user);
        var_dump($usr);
        echo($usr->nome);
        echo($user->nome);
    }
}
```

Se eu dou um `var_dump($user)` ele retorna:

`string(38) "{\"nome\":\"alvaro\",\"idade\":\"34\"}"`

e o `var_dump($usr)` retorna `NULL`.

Os Dois `echo()` não mostram o nome.
Como faço para pegar estes dados?

Comment: o var `dump($newUsers);` traz um array: `array(3) { [0]=> string(38) "{\"nome\":\"alvaro\",\"idade\":\"34\"}" [1]=> string(34) "{\"nome\":\"bia\",\"idade\":\"7\"}" [2]=> string(36) "{\"nome\":\"alice\",\"idade\":\"2\"}"}`

Comment: Estou usando PHP 5.2. Parece que o problema é com meu json_decode

Comment: Percebi que no meu var_dump($users) ele traz uma string `string(38) ` antes  do item do array `"{\"nome\":\"alvaro\",\"idade\":\"34\"}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a sua versão de PHP não tem `json_decode`, fazer isso sem `json_decode` dá mais trabalho.

Partindo do principio que o array tem sempre dados desse tipo (`"chave":"valor"`) deve dar para usar assim:

```
foreach ($newUsers as $user) {
   preg_match_all('/(\w+)[^\w]*([\p{L}\d\s]+)/', $user, $partes, PREG_SET_ORDER);
   $nome = $partes[0][2];
   $idade = $partes[1][2];
   echo 'O nome é: '.$nome.', e a idade é: '.$idade.'<br/>';
}
```

Nota: Juntei `\s` no regex para permitir frases com espaços também.

#### PHPFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ur56-1vrg